# Google Analytics Event Tracking Form select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

i´m trying to track the selected option values. I´m getting this error in console when i track the form:

```
Expected a number value for the field: "eventValue". but found: "string".
```

html code:

```
<select name="fornoyd_service_nybil" id="liste_nybil" class="liste">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
```

JS tracking code:

```
$('#liste_nybil').on('click', function () {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Fornøyd', 'Click', 'Nybil', document.getElementById('liste_nybil').value);
});
```

Is there a different method for doing this?

Comment: did this issue prevent your events from being tracked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytic is expecting a numeric datatype, and you're giving it a string.

You can convert that string to a number by doing any of the following (depending on your preference):

- `+document.getElementById('liste_nybil').value`
- `parseInt(document.getElementById('liste_nybil').value, 10);`
- `Number(document.getElementById('liste_nybil').value);`

So your updated code might look like this:

```
$('#liste_nybil').on('click', function () {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Fornøyd', 'Click', 'Nybil', +document.getElementById('liste_nybil').value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the string error. Is there a method for only post the value the user select? Now it post the first "" '0' value.

Comment: You can just add a conditional inside that function to only send that value in certain cases.